# Why is typescript inferring the generic type to be type ""

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created this React component called StateWithValidation.

```html
import { useStateWithValidation } from "./useStateWithValidation";

export const StateWithValidation = () => {
  const [username, setUserName, isValid] = useStateWithValidation(
    (value: string) => value.length > 5,
    ""
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Valid: {isValid.toString()}</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a custom hook which is generic, it validates and handles user input changes.

```html
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

type useStateValidationFn = <U>(
  validationFunc: (value: U) => boolean,
  initialState: U
) => [U, (nextState: U) => void, boolean];

export const useStateWithValidation: useStateValidationFn = (
  validationFunc,
  initialValue
) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(() => validationFunc(state));

  const onChange = useCallback(
    (nextState) => {
      setState(nextState);
      setIsValid(validationFunc(nextState));
    },
    [validationFunc]
  );

  return [state, onChange, isValid];
};
```

Why is it when I type in the React component, the value of the generic type is "" instead of string.

[image]

Comment: because your initial state is ""... add<string> when using your hook,

Comment: Why isn't it inferring from the method I passed (value: string) => value.length > 5 ?

Comment: This is an interesting question; I'm surprised that there's a literal context here at all.  Might be related to [ms/TS#43804](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43804), might not be.  Research hasn't turned up anything definitive yet.

Comment: Yeah I haven't been able to find an answer to this; generally speaking if you had `T extends string` then you can expect string literal types like `""` to be inferred, but just `T` with no constraints usually infers widened types like `string`.  The [mre] for this might be [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wX2Vkm).  Someone (you?) might want to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) asking what's going on.  I will keep looking for a bit but I'm not optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing as below

```
const [username, setUserName, isValid] = useStateWithValidation(
    (value: string) => value.length > 5,
    new String()
  );
```

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use [`String` as a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String#examples); you could write `String()` instead, or `"" as string`.  Also note that the question seems to be "why is this happening" and not "how can I work around it"

Comment: This will work and the type will be inferred to String instead of string. But we will get an error that <input value={username} /> only accepts value of type string not String. We will have to do then <input value={username.toString()}>.

Comment: @jcalz Well I don't really want to workaround it. It can be fixed easily by typing useStateWithValidation<string>(
    (value: string) => value.length > 5,
    ""
  );. I don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: @Dusan I think we are on the same page? You're not asking how to fix it (which is easy enough) but why it's happening (which is... not easy for me to answer)